# Выгрузка информации в файл с heroku

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть бот, загруженный на heroku, как мне прописать в нем, чтоб вся информация сохранялась в онлайн таблицу какую-нибудь?
Если бот запущен локально, то все просто:

```
newlist=split(td_list,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)
df.to_csv("C:/orders.csv", encoding='utf-8',sep='\t')
```

А вот что делать, если бот запущен на серваке....

Comment: Heroku это не воркспейс, грузите в бд, либо в гугл таблицы

Comment: Подключать хранилище [внешним сервисом](https://www.heroku.com/products).